# Why do these two functions not return the same result?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to update a function to improve performance.
The old function takes ~32s and the new one takes ~350ms for the same call, but right now they are not returning the same result, and I'm not sure why.

#### Function parameters:

- md5Hashes: array of strings
- excludedTextId: string

#### What the function is supposed to do:

It is using the following mongoose schema:

```
const sentenceFeatureSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text_id: { type: String, required: true },
    md5_hash: { type: String, required: true },
    offset: { type: Number, required: true },
    length: { type: Number, required: true },
    num_words: { type: Number, required: true },
});
```

Given an array of hashes, query mongodb for all documents which match any of the md5 hashes in the given array. If excludedTextId is provided, do not include those documents which have the same textId. The hashes and textids are not exclusive, meaning that any document can have any combination of textid and hash (there can even be multiple documents which have both the same id and hash, but will differ in other values).

Note: It should only be querying for the data it needs, because there are a lot of documents in the system, so trying to query for more than we need and then using only what we need must be avoided.

#### Problem

My new implementation is not returning the same result as the original one. I believe the new implementation is correct and the old one is not, but I may be wrong. Either way, I'd like to understand exactly what and why they are returning different results.

#### Original function

```js
const getMatchingHashSentences = async (md5Hashes, excludedTextId = null) => {
    try {
        const entries = [];

        for (const md5Hash of md5Hashes) {
            const queryConditions = { md5_hash: md5Hash };
            if (excludedTextId) {
                queryConditions.text_id = { $ne: excludedTextId };
            }
            const result = await SentenceFeature.find(queryConditions);
            entries.push(...result);
        }
        logger.debug(`entries length: ${entries.length}`);
        return entries;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};
```

#### New function

I tried to make it into a single db request.

```js
const getMatchingHashSentences = async (md5Hashes, excludedTextId = null) => {
    try {
        const query = SentenceFeature.find({ md5_hash: { $in: md5Hashes } });

        if (excludedTextId) {
            query.where("text_id").ne(excludedTextId);
        }

        const results = await query.exec();
        return results;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};
```

#### *EDIT*

As was requested, here is demo code that will create 10 elements and use both functions to query for them:

demo directory:
`mkdir demo && cd demo`

barebones npm project:
`npm init -y && npm i mongoose mongodb`

create demo.js:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

// Define schema

const sentenceFeatureSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text_id: { type: String, required: true },
    md5_hash: { type: String, required: true },
    offset: { type: Number, required: true },
    length: { type: Number, required: true },
    num_words: { type: Number, required: true },
});

// Define model
const SentenceFeature = mongoose.model("features", sentenceFeatureSchema);

const getMatchingHashSentences = async (md5Hashes, excludedTextId = null) => {
    try {
        const entries = [];

        for (const md5Hash of md5Hashes) {
            const queryConditions = { md5_hash: md5Hash };
            if (excludedTextId) {
                queryConditions.text_id = { $ne: excludedTextId };
            }
            const result = await SentenceFeature.find(queryConditions);
            entries.push(...result);
        }
        return entries;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};

const getMatchingHashSentences2 = async (md5Hashes, excludedTextId = null) => {
    try {
        const query = SentenceFeature.find({ md5_hash: { $in: md5Hashes } });

        if (excludedTextId) {
            query.where("text_id").ne(excludedTextId);
        }

        const results = await query.exec();
        return results;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose
    .connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mydatabase", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Connected to MongoDB");

        const feature = new Feature({
            text_id: "1",
            md5_hash: "h1",
            offset: 0,
            length: 0,
            num_words: 0,
        });

        feature
            .save()
            .then(() => {
                console.log("Entry saved successfully");
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error("Error saving entry:", err);
            });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error connecting to MongoDB:", err);
    });

async function main() {
    try {
        // Connect to MongoDB
        await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mydatabase", {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        });
        console.log("Connected to MongoDB");

        // Save 10 features

        for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            const feature = new SentenceFeature({
                text_id: `${i}`,
                md5_hash: `h${i}`,
                offset: 0,
                length: 0,
                num_words: 0,
            });
            await feature.save();
            console.log(`Saved Feature ${i}`);
        }

        // Query for saved features
        const oldres = await getMatchingHashSentences(["h1", "h3", "h6"], "3");
        console.log("old:", oldres);

        const newres = await getMatchingHashSentences2(["h1", "h3", "h6"], "3");
        console.log("new:", newres);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
    } finally {
        // Close connection
        await mongoose.disconnect();
        console.log("Disconnected from MongoDB");
    }
}

main();

// OUTPUT:

// Saved Feature 1
// Saved Feature 2
// Saved Feature 3
// Saved Feature 4
// Saved Feature 5
// Saved Feature 6
// Saved Feature 7
// Saved Feature 8
// Saved Feature 9
// Saved Feature 10
// old: [
//   {
//     _id: new ObjectId('6605aa98790f41e69f3f966b'),
//     text_id: '1',
//     md5_hash: 'h1',
//     offset: 0,
//     length: 0,
//     num_words: 0,
//     __v: 0
//   },
//   {
//     _id: new ObjectId('6605aa98790f41e69f3f9676'),
//     text_id: '6',
//     md5_hash: 'h6',
//     offset: 0,
//     length: 0,
//     num_words: 0,
//     __v: 0
//   }
// ]
// new: [
//   {
//     _id: new ObjectId('6605aa98790f41e69f3f966b'),
//     text_id: '1',
//     md5_hash: 'h1',
//     offset: 0,
//     length: 0,
//     num_words: 0,
//     __v: 0
//   },
//   {
//     _id: new ObjectId('6605aa98790f41e69f3f9676'),
//     text_id: '6',
//     md5_hash: 'h6',
//     offset: 0,
//     length: 0,
//     num_words: 0,
//     __v: 0
//   }
// ]
// Disconnected from MongoDB
```

start up one-time docker container for mogodb:
`docker run --rm -d -p 27017:27017 --name my-mongodb mongo`

finally, run the demo:
`node demo.js`

You will notice that the output of the 2 functions is the same for such a small example, which is normal. There must be some strange edge case that results in the difference of output when running the queries on larger amounts of data.

Comment: how are results different? I can see the old function spreads each result and pushes it into the `entries` array, while your new function returns the whole `results` object; could be that?

Comment: @GrafiCode The old function defines an empty array and then has to use the spread operator when pushing the results in because they are in arrays, so the end result would be an array of arrays of results, but we want one array with the results. In terms of how they differ, the old function returns more hits (eg. 20k versus 5k for the new one for some specific call), which is making me think that there is some sort of overlap in it, but I can't seem to understand it.

Comment: wait a second, if you spread the result and push it inside an "entries" array, then `entries.length` would not match the number of records returned from DB, it should give number of result multiplied by the number of fields... is it not?

Comment: Have you tried creating a [mcve] with e.g 10 entries? Can you provide this [mcve] and the actual output?

Comment: @GrafiCode The old function queries the database multiple times, so they need to be all added up into the "final" array that is then returned. This is not needed in the new function because it makes a single request which is supposed to be the same as the final combined array of the old function (by making use of mongodb's $in operator).

Comment: @jabaa It's quite difficult to do because of all the components the code relies on to work in the first place. If there is a way to mimic a mongodb database in simple js code, then I can definitely make one.

Comment: I meant you should create a new, empty Mongo database and add 10 entries. Then, run your [mcve] with these 10 entries and compare the results. Post the results in the question. You can try to use embedded MongoDB. I'm not sure if it works with Node.js or only with Java Spring

Comment: [TingoDB](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tingodb) looks like a drop-in embedded MongoDB replacement.

Comment: @jabaa I've edited the question to include a minimal setup which can run the code, but you'll notice that the result is the same on such a small data set. The thing that makes the output differ on a large database is what I don't understand and why I said it is hard to provide a decent example.

Comment: Play with the data and debug your code until you're able to provide a [mcve]. How could anybody help you if you can't produce the problem?

Comment: @jabaa Because it's restricted to only this function, I think that someone who's experienced at using mongoose would be able to quickly see a the semantic error based on my description of how the function is supposed to work. If I had the time to rebuild the whole problem and test it bit by bit until I found the problem, then I would not be posting this question.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @jabaa Yes, ideally this would be the process of asking the question, but I've already stated why I ended up asking it. What takes an expert 1-4 minutes to solve compared to potentially days of me trying things not working just doesn't add up.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform for specific questions with the goal to help future users with similar problems, not to help one individual user. This concept only works when the question contains all necessary details to reproduce the problem. If you can't reproduce the problem yourself, the question won't be of much value for future users. If you want an expert to help you with your individual problem, consider hiring an expert.

Comment: You wrote that one code produces 20k results and the other code produces 5k results. Put those results into a table, sort the table and add three results to the question. One result from both codes, one result only in the first code and one result only in the second code. Create an [mcve] with only these 3 entries. There should be 15k examples for edge cases in your data. 75% of your data should be edge cases

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up doing a bunch of manual testing, and in the end the findings are as follows:

- The **original function does not work as it should** based on the requirement, because it sometimes produces duplicate results. (I did not investigate exactly in which cases, but it has to do with overlap between the different calls, because it would never occur when using a one element hash array).
- The **new function is much faster and works correctly**. Keep in mind that there are multiple ways of implementing it, like constructing the whole query condition first and applying it in the end, or like I did it, creating a query object first and conditionally modifying it later ([further reading](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.find())).

Comment: Your self-answer is not really explaining anything.